# angular JS isNotWorking inMyProject

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a project now. It includes Django, postgreSQL, Mongodb, python and angular js.

Its working in google-chrome, firefox IE 11.0, IE 10.0, and IE 9.0. But its not working in IE

8.0, IE 7.0 and IE 6.0.

I think it is the problem with angularjs because of the support for different browsers.

help me if you can...

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS does support IE8 please follow this link http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie and apply the workaround mentioned there. If you want to support older IE versions then please use a library which claims to supports them.

Answer (score 1):

This seems correct. Check this page for IE compability: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie